# Arcgis js 4.11: How to add basemap layer to basemap gallery

Tags: javascript, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

How to add basemap in basemap gallery. In default BasemapGallery class, we have only 5 basemap layers. But how we can add another/custom basemap layer to that BasemapGallery?

Here is the default layers provided by BasemapGallery.

[image]

But I want to add more basemap layers like:-

[image]

Please help on this.

Comment: I see all 12 in the demo: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/sandbox/index.html?sample=widgets-basemapgallery

Comment: @GavinR Thanks for reply. But I can see only 5. Can you let me know how I can see all of the 12 like you?

Comment: I think maybe you're logged into your ArcGIS Online org? Try opening that link on a separate computer or in a Private/Incognito browser window. When you do that, do you see 12?

Comment: Yeah.. it seems you are right. But I'm using arcgis in my application. Here in using its Basemap gallery. Here how can I show all of these basemaps?

Comment: Have you tried adding manually basemap collection to the widget?

Comment: Yes I added basemap collection manually to the widget. above first screenshot is the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you need to create a group inside arcgis account.
[Here](http://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/portal/latest/administer/windows/customize-basemaps.htm) is the documentation of create group and how you can add custom basemaps to the group.

After it open group and copy id from url

[image]

And use below code in you application to add basemap gallary on the map

```
let basemapGallery = new BasemapGallery({
  source: { // autocasts as PortalBasemapsSource
    query: {
      //title: "ArcGIS Online Basemaps",owner: "esri"
      id: '702026e41f6641fb85da88efe79dc166'
    }
  },
  view: view
});

view.ui.add(basemapGallery, 'bottom-left');
```

After that you will get this output

[image]

I hope it will help you.

Comment: ah.. got that.. Thanks @gurpreet. understand what I'm missing.